# Javascript Convert WMS url to coordinate?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I'm looking for some hints (Javascript custom function or openlayers 4 function) ...) that can help me to convert a wms response URL parameters to get my click coordinates.

Here an example of url to convert to a click coordinate.

```
https://ws.mapserver.transports.gouv.qc.ca/swtq?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&BBOX=-7859605.72457123640924692,5954835.61684618983417749,-7802662.21180228982120752,5988064.99139707256108522
&CRS=EPSG:3857
&WIDTH=1155
&HEIGHT=674
&LAYERS=histo_stations_meteoroutieres
&STYLES=
&FORMAT=image/png
&QUERY_LAYERS=histo_stations_meteoroutieres
&INFO_FORMAT=text/html
&I=722
&J=403
&FEATURE_COUNT=10
```

My goal is to recreate a gml from this query based on derived wkt Point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click coordinates are 722,403 px on a window that is 1155x674px with a real world bounding box of -7859605.72457123640924692, 5954835.61684618983417749, -7802662.21180228982120752, 5988064.99139707256108522.

So simple maths gives you

```
x = (-7802662.2118022898212 - -7859605.72457123640924692) * 722/1155
y = (5988064.99139707256108522 - 5954835.61684618983417749) * 403/674
```

converting to javascript is left as an exercise for the reader.

But if it was me I'd remember the event coordinates I used to construct the URL in the first place.

Comment: But how to manage the correct projection as with local projection (utm?) how the coordinates increases?

Comment: that doesn't matter

Comment: This calculation, can you tell me a little?